# gRPC client/server authentication on Windows

Tags: grpc

I am trying to hook a Xamarin (Maui, really) C# client up to a Xamarin C# server. Server is a command-line app, Client has GUI. Both machines are on the same network, on the same domain.

I don't do this kind of stuff day to day, so it's a mystery to me. I guess my server runs Kestrel (which I've never heard of before) in the background, and I have it set up to provide Http1AndHttp2. The client tries to connect with:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl,
    ThrowOperationCanceledOnCancellation = false
});
```

but still, the client won't connect. They're logged in with the same credentials on both machines. (but let's assume they're both logged in with different credentials on the same domain).

When the client tries to connect, it gets an authentication failure, something about how it doesn't trust the remote certificate. I've tried to follow along instructions about what, specifically, minimally, needs to be done to get that working, but the advice on the internet is all OVER the place, and almost certainly the bulk of it seems like it's probably wrong or overkill.

Answer (score 0):

had to do this on the client:

```
var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
// Return `true` to allow certificates that are untrusted/invalid
socketsHandler.SslOptions = new System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate 
    { 
        return true; 
    }
};

string BaseAddress = "https://" + szConnection + ":7201";
var baseUri = new Uri(BaseAddress);
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl,
    ThrowOperationCanceledOnCancellation = false,
    HttpHandler = socketsHandler
});
```